# jsonparser give error app does not insert data

Tags: android, json

i am studying about json parser and i was making an app by seeing a demo 
i done line by line as they told in demo but my app does not works 
and the answer of my problem was not on that site kindly guide me thanks in advance

my log cat is

```
10-25 15:16:05.766 1996-1996/com.example.ahmed.json E/Trace: error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
10-25 15:16:14.484 1996-2310/com.example.ahmed.json E/Buffer Error: Error converting result java.lang.NullPointerException
10-25 15:16:14.484 1996-2310/com.example.ahmed.json E/JSON Parser: Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of 
10-25 15:16:14.516 1996-2310/com.example.ahmed.json E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
10-25 15:16:14.516 1996-2310/com.example.ahmed.json E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
10-25 15:16:14.516 1996-2310/com.example.ahmed.json E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
10-25 15:16:14.516 1996-2310/com.example.ahmed.json E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
10-25 15:16:14.516 1996-2310/com.example.ahmed.json E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
10-25 15:16:14.516 1996-2310/com.example.ahmed.json E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
10-25 15:16:14.516 1996-2310/com.example.ahmed.json E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
10-25 15:16:14.516 1996-2310/com.example.ahmed.json E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
10-25 15:16:14.516 1996-2310/com.example.ahmed.json E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
10-25 15:16:14.516 1996-2310/com.example.ahmed.json E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
10-25 15:16:14.516 1996-2310/com.example.ahmed.json E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
10-25 15:16:14.516 1996-2310/com.example.ahmed.json E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-25 15:16:14.516 1996-2310/com.example.ahmed.json E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.example.ahmed.json.MainActivity$InsertNewIdiom.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:76)
10-25 15:16:14.516 1996-2310/com.example.ahmed.json E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.example.ahmed.json.MainActivity$InsertNewIdiom.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:57)
10-25 15:16:14.516 1996-2310/com.example.ahmed.json E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
10-25 15:16:14.516 1996-2310/com.example.ahmed.json E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
10-25 15:16:14.516 1996-2310/com.example.ahmed.json E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137) 
10-25 15:16:14.516 1996-2310/com.example.ahmed.json E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230) 
10-25 15:16:14.516 1996-2310/com.example.ahmed.json E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076) 
10-25 15:16:14.516 1996-2310/com.example.ahmed.json E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569) 
10-25 15:16:14.516 1996-2310/com.example.ahmed.json E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856) 
10-25 15:16:15.680 1996-1996/com.example.ahmed.json E/WindowManager: Activity com.example.ahmed.json.MainActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@41972358 that was originally added here
10-25 15:16:15.680 1996-1996/com.example.ahmed.json E/WindowManager: android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.example.ahmed.json.MainActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@41972358 that was originally added here
10-25 15:16:15.680 1996-1996/com.example.ahmed.json E/WindowManager:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:382)
10-25 15:16:15.680 1996-1996/com.example.ahmed.json E/WindowManager:     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:292)
10-25 15:16:15.680 1996-1996/com.example.ahmed.json E/WindowManager:     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:224)
10-25 15:16:15.680 1996-1996/com.example.ahmed.json E/WindowManager:     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl$CompatModeWrapper.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:149)
10-25 15:16:15.680 1996-1996/com.example.ahmed.json E/WindowManager:     at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:547)
10-25 15:16:15.680 1996-1996/com.example.ahmed.json E/WindowManager:     at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:284)
10-25 15:16:15.680 1996-1996/com.example.ahmed.json E/WindowManager:     at com.example.ahmed.json.MainActivity$InsertNewIdiom.onPreExecute(MainActivity.java:68)
10-25 15:16:15.680 1996-1996/com.example.ahmed.json E/WindowManager:     at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:586)
10-25 15:16:15.680 1996-1996/com.example.ahmed.json E/WindowManager:     at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:534)
10-25 15:16:15.680 1996-1996/com.example.ahmed.json E/WindowManager:     at com.example.ahmed.json.MainActivity.onClick(MainActivity.java:47)
10-25 15:16:15.680 1996-1996/com.example.ahmed.json E/WindowManager:     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4106)
10-25 15:16:15.680 1996-1996/com.example.ahmed.json E/WindowManager:     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17052)
10-25 15:16:15.680 1996-1996/com.example.ahmed.json E/WindowManager:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
10-25 15:16:15.680 1996-1996/com.example.ahmed.json E/WindowManager:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
10-25 15:16:15.680 1996-1996/com.example.ahmed.json E/WindowManager:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-25 15:16:15.680 1996-1996/com.example.ahmed.json E/WindowManager:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5059)
10-25 15:16:15.680 1996-1996/com.example.ahmed.json E/WindowManager:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-25 15:16:15.680 1996-1996/com.example.ahmed.json E/WindowManager:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-25 15:16:15.680 1996-1996/com.example.ahmed.json E/WindowManager:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:792)
10-25 15:16:15.680 1996-1996/com.example.ahmed.json E/WindowManager:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:555)
10-25 15:16:15.680 1996-1996/com.example.ahmed.json E/WindowManager:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

my mainactivity is

```
package com.example.ahmed.json;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends Activity
    implements OnClickListener {
private ProgressDialog pDialog;
JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
 EditText txtnewidiom;
 EditText txtmeaning;
private Button btnsavenew;
private int success;
private static String url_insert_new = "http://10.0.2.2/idiomjson/insertnew.php";
private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    txtnewidiom = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtnewidiom);
    txtmeaning = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtmeaning);
    btnsavenew = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnsavenew);
    btnsavenew.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if
            (v.getId() == R.id.btnsavenew) {
        new InsertNewIdiom().execute();

        if (success == 1) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "New idiom saved...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "New idiom FAILED to saved...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}

class InsertNewIdiom extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    String entry = txtnewidiom.getText().toString();
    String meaning = txtmeaning.getText().toString();

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Saving the new IDIOM (" + entry + ")...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("entry", entry));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("meaning", meaning));
        JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_insert_new, "GET", params);
        Log.d("Insert New Idiom Response", json.toString());
        try {
            success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
            if (success == 1) { // successfully save new idiom
            } else {
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        pDialog.dismiss();
    }
}
}
```

json parser's class is

```
package com.example.ahmed.json;

import android.util.Log;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.client.utils.URLEncodedUtils;    
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.List;


public class JSONParser {
static InputStream is = null;
static JSONObject jObj = null;
static String json = "";
public JSONParser() {
}
public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method, List<NameValuePair> params)
{  try
{
    if(method == "POST")
    {
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
        httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));
        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        is = httpEntity.getContent();
    }
    else if(method == "GET"){
     DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8"); url += "?" + paramString;
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        is = httpEntity.getContent();
    }
}
catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
    try { BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader( is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
        { sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close(); json = sb.toString();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString()); }
         try {
             jObj = new JSONObject(json);
         }
         catch (JSONException e) {
             Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
         }
    return jObj;
}
    }
```

after try if else on json it give this error

```
10-29 00:48:14.446 29434-29434/com.example.ahmed.json E/Trace: error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)

10-29 00:48:39.017 29434-29434/com.example.ahmed.json E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-29 00:48:39.017 29434-29434/com.example.ahmed.json E/AndroidRuntime: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
10-29 00:48:39.017 29434-29434/com.example.ahmed.json E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1131)
10-29 00:48:39.017 29434-29434/com.example.ahmed.json E/AndroidRuntime:     at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.connect(BlockGuardOs.java:84)
10-29 00:48:39.017 29434-29434/com.example.ahmed.json E/AndroidRuntime:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:127)
10-29 00:48:39.017 29434-29434/com.example.ahmed.json E/AndroidRuntime:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:112)
10-29 00:48:39.017 29434-29434/com.example.ahmed.json E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:192)
10-29 00:48:39.017 29434-29434/com.example.ahmed.json E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:460)
10-29 00:48:39.017 29434-29434/com.example.ahmed.json E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:832)
10-29 00:48:39.017 29434-29434/com.example.ahmed.json E/AndroidRuntime:     at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:119)
10-29 00:48:39.017 29434-29434/com.example.ahmed.json E/AndroidRuntime:     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:144)
10-29 00:48:39.017 29434-29434/com.example.ahmed.json E/AndroidRuntime:     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
10-29 00:48:39.017 29434-29434/com.example.ahmed.json E/AndroidRuntime:     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
10-29 00:48:39.017 29434-29434/com.example.ahmed.json E/AndroidRuntime:     at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)
10-29 00:48:39.017 29434-29434/com.example.ahmed.json E/AndroidRuntime:     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
10-29 00:48:39.017 29434-29434/com.example.ahmed.json E/AndroidRuntime:     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
10-29 00:48:39.017 29434-29434/com.example.ahmed.json E/AndroidRuntime:     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
10-29 00:48:39.017 29434-29434/com.example.ahmed.json E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.example.ahmed.json.JSONParser.makeHttpRequest(JSONParser.java:47)
10-29 00:48:39.017 29434-29434/com.example.ahmed.json E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.example.ahmed.json.MainActivity$InsertNewIdiom.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:75)
10-29 00:48:39.017 29434-29434/com.example.ahmed.json E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.example.ahmed.json.MainActivity.onClick(MainActivity.java:47)
10-29 00:48:39.017 29434-29434/com.example.ahmed.json E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4106)
10-29 00:48:39.017 29434-29434/com.example.ahmed.json E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17052)
10-29 00:48:39.017 29434-29434/com.example.ahmed.json E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
10-29 00:48:39.017 29434-29434/com.example.ahmed.json E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
10-29 00:48:39.017 29434-29434/com.example.ahmed.json E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-29 00:48:39.017 29434-29434/com.example.ahmed.json E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5059)
10-29 00:48:39.017 29434-29434/com.example.ahmed.json E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-29 00:48:39.017 29434-29434/com.example.ahmed.json E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-29 00:48:39.017 29434-29434/com.example.ahmed.json E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:792)
10-29 00:48:39.017 29434-29434/com.example.ahmed.json E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:555)
10-29 00:48:39.017 29434-29434/com.example.ahmed.json E/AndroidRuntime:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

sorry i have forgot to give php file

```
<?php
 //insertnew.php /* * Following code will create a new product row * All product details are read from HTTP GET Request */ // array for JSON response 
$response = array();
 // check for required fields 
if (isset($_GET['entry']) && isset($_GET['meaning'])) { 
$entry = $_GET['entry']; 
$meaning = $_GET['meaning'];
 // include db connect class 
require_once __DIR__ . '/connect.php';
 // connecting to db 
$db = new DB_CONNECT();
 // mysql inserting a new row (idioms) 
$result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO idiomlist(entry, meaning) VALUES('$entry', '$meaning')");
 // check if row inserted or not 
if ($result) { 
// successfully inserted into database 
$response["success"] = 1; $response["message"] = "new IDIOM saved...."; 
// echoing JSON response 
echo json_encode($response);
 }
else { 
// failed to insert row 
$response["success"] = 0;
$response["message"] = "Oops! An error occurred.";
// echoing JSON response 
echo json_encode($response);
}
} 
else { 
// required field is missing 
$response["success"] = 0; 
$response["message"] = "Required field(s) is missing"; 
// echoing JSON response 
echo json_encode($response);
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Caused by: java.lang.**NullPointerException** 10-25 15:16:14.516
>   1996-2310/com.example.ahmed.json E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   com.example.ahmed.json.MainActivity$InsertNewIdiom.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:76)

Make sure `json != null` before using it.

Because `jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_insert_new, "GET", params);` can return a `null` value.

Comment: thanks for help 
sir kindly guide me how should i do it, i have little knowledge about this

Comment: sir you are right it's value is null i have check it in if else condition that if (json!=null){do work}
else{Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "json value is null", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();}
and it shows value is null

Comment: now it give following errors
E/AndroidRuntime:     at .JSONParser.makeHttpRequest(JSONParser.java:47)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at .MainActivity$InsertNewIdiom.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:75)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at .MainActivity.onClick(MainActivity.java:47)

Comment: Post the full logcat, we can figure out the error origin from this portion.

Comment: it giving the value of json null 
when i try with it it give the error which is in my new logcat

Comment: **NetworkOnMainThreadException** don't make your http request in main thread. Use an AsyncTask instead.

Comment: kindly guide me how should i do it

Comment: i have try so much but i am not able to put all the code in asyntack on stackflow i have seen that we can use strictmodepolicy to complete our app i have try it but it is giving the same null value of json

Comment: i  will be thankful to you if you can guide me how to make it in asyntack i have seach many question like this stackoverflow.com/questions/6343166/… but i m not able to build a right asyntack because in doInback method i have to make an another method of public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method, List<NameValuePair> params) { when i try to write this it give error and when i fix that error another error come in main activity on line 75 i-e JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_insert_new, "GET", params)

Answer (score 0):

> 10-25 15:16:14.516 1996-2310/com.example.ahmed.json E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>   10-25 15:16:14.516 1996-2310/com.example.ahmed.json E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.example.ahmed.json.MainActivity$InsertNewIdiom.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:76)
>   10-25 15:16:14.516 1996-2310/com.example.ahmed.json E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.example.ahmed.json.MainActivity$InsertNewIdiom.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:57)
>   10-25 15:16:14.516 1996-2310/com.example.ahmed.json E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)

`jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_insert_new, "GET", params);` return `null` .
Maybe this local url `http://10.0.2.2/idiomjson/insertnew.php` is an exmaple and invalid for you.

Comment: what should i insert for default value of my local database?

Comment: i have insert the value 127.0.0.1 but it still give same error