# how to make a method in asynctask

Tags: android, json, android-asynctask

Kindly guide me how to make all this into an asynctask method. I have to make this code in asynctask because it is giving a null value because of calling it in uithread. Kindly show me the correct way how to make this possible. I have seen many, many questions on stackoverflow but I am unable to make this work.

I have seen following questions:

[How to fix android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343166/android-os-networkonmainthreadexception)

[android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException with android 4.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16439587/android-os-networkonmainthreadexception-with-android-4-2)

[NetworkOnMainThreadException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5150637/networkonmainthreadexception)

[android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12615607/android-os-networkonmainthreadexception/12615724#12615724)

[How to fix android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343166/android-os-networkonmainthreadexception)

My class is:

```
public class JSONParser {
static InputStream is = null;
static JSONObject jObj = null;
static String json = "";
public JSONParser() {
}
public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method, List<NameValuePair> params)
{  try
{
if(method == "POST")
{
    DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
    httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));
    HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
    HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
    is = httpEntity.getContent();
}
else if(method == "GET"){
 DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8"); url += "?" + paramString;
    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
    HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
    HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
    is = httpEntity.getContent();
}
}
catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
catch (IOException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
try { BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader( is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String line = null;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
    { sb.append(line + "\n");
    }
    is.close(); json = sb.toString();
}
catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString()); }
     try {
         jObj = new JSONObject(json);
     }
     catch (JSONException e) {
         Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
     }
return jObj;
}
}
```

Comment: You should go through a few tutorials. There is a class named `AsyncTask` that you can use. which has pretty useful overrides. Search for it.

Comment: i have search and i does not help me enough to resolve this problem that's why i have ask this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Ebad, you have answered your own question use an asynctask like the following:

```
class GetJsonTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, JSONObject>
{
    List<NameValuePair> params;

    public CreateNewProduct(List<NameValuePair> params){
      this.params = params;
    }

    protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... urls)
    {
        JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
        JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url[0],"POST", this.params);

        return json;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject result)
    {
      //parse the result here  
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
GetJsonTask jsonTask = new GetJsonTask(params);
jsonTask.execute("http://example.com");
```

Comment: in my main activity i have call the method of makehttprequest
when i try to make this method in method of doInBackground method of asynctask  it give error when i solve that error a new error comes on mainactivity line 75 i-e JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_insert_new, "GET", params);

Comment: @EbadAhmed I updated my answer on how to use the task, if you get errors you need to tell me which one specifically as I cannot guesss

Comment: what do you mean by parse the result here ?
and should i copy your code and replace mine?

Comment: yes use my code, parse mean you can read the values in post execute,

Comment: what is mean by usage and that where should i paste that code?
and thanks for helping me

Comment: you call it where you want , for example `onCreate()` and you can log the json in `onPostExecute()` like this `Log.d("mylog", "json =" + result);`

Comment: i m new in app development
sir i am bit confused
this class is just a part of project 
i am not able to figure out what you  are trying to teach me 
because i have to wrote that is my main activity
sir i would like to show you my activity but then this question will become a duplicate 
i am giving you the link of my main question 
i will b thankful to you if you are going to help me  

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33328578/jsonparser-give-error-app-does-not-insert-data/33328669?noredirect=1#comment54595346_33328669

Comment: I see your code but not where you used `InsertNewIdiom` can you show me where it is

Comment: thank you sir for your help
it is in onclick method which is in on create method which is in
 mainactivity